# what hash function is being used by boost c++ unordered_map?

Tags: c++, boost, hash, hash-function

what hash function is being used by boost c++ unordered_map ? I meant what kind of hash algorithms being used by boost::hash, for  example

template<> struct hash;

Thanks

Comment: http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/unordered.html

Comment: @Noah: At least link to the [newest version](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/unordered.html). :P

Comment: It hasn't changed.  Point made regardless I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the type you are using, if you look [here](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#header.boost.functional.hash_hpp) the `boost::hash` template class is specialised:

```
  template<> struct hash<bool>;
  template<> struct hash<char>;
  template<> struct hash<signed char>;
  template<> struct hash<unsigned char>;
  template<> struct hash<wchar_t>;
  template<> struct hash<short>;
  template<> struct hash<unsigned short>;
  template<> struct hash<int>;
  template<> struct hash<unsigned int>;
  template<> struct hash<long>;
  template<> struct hash<unsigned long>;
  template<> struct hash<long long>;
  template<> struct hash<unsigned long long>;
  template<> struct hash<float>;
  template<> struct hash<double>;
  template<> struct hash<long double>;
  template<> struct hash<std::string>;
  template<> struct hash<std::wstring>;
  template<typename T> struct hash<T*>;
```

You can also specify your own hash as the third template argument:

```
namespace boost {
  template<typename Key, typename Mapped, typename Hash = boost::hash<Key>, 
           typename Pred = std::equal_to<Key>, 
           typename Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, Mapped> > > 
    class unordered_map;
```

Answer (score 9):

By default, it uses [boost::hash](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost/hash.html) :)